# What happens if remove auto eth0 from /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: debian, network-interface, ethernet, ppp, beagleboneblack

I am using a BeagleBone and have two network interfaces. One Ethernet interface which will connect locally to another device, and a ppp interface over USB which connects to a cellular modem.

I want the ppp connection to start automatically on boot-up and connect to the modem which I have set up running a script in `rc.local`. The ppp interface then receives a dynamic IP address from the ISP. This is fine

For the Ethernet interface I would like a static IP address assigned to it , and for it to start automatically also. However, when I set *auto eth0* in the /etc/network/interfaces file, the ppp interface then is not available on boot-up automatically as I would like.

What is the problem if I remove the line auto eth0 ? How can I enable both interfaces automatically? Thanks

Below is my `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#static IP address for eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.80
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

For your first question:

If you remove `auto eth0` then your `eth0` interface won't start at boot.

If what you've posted is all your `/etc/network/interface` content where is the `ppp` connection configuration? Do you have your `DNS` configured?

**FOLLOW-UP**

All right. If you have your `ppp` working that's fine. To set a static IP you may need to have your `DNS` configured and add the following to your `/etc/network/interfaces` in addition to what you have already

```
BROADCAST        192.168.1.255
DNS-NAMESERVERS  8.8.8.8 # Supply here your DNS
```

I would rather have `allow-hotplug` instead of `auto` since the former allows the detection of events after the boot.

Comment: That's the thing. I have a separate script which executes the pppd command as given on the modem user manual. When I run the pppd command , then check ifconfig, I see my ppp interface. However i'm not sure if I need to configure this in the network/interfaces file. I'm new to this ppp stuff